# How to pass navigation props to presentational component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

For a `Flatlist`, I have created a presentational component and pass items as props to child component which is working fine. Now, I am using `TouchableOpacity` in presentational component and `navigate` it to different component. How can I achieve this.?

MyFlastList:

```
_renderItem({item, index}) {
        return(
            <View>
              {index == 0 && <MachineInformationCard {...item}/>}
              {index > 0 && <MachineFunctionality {...item} />}   
            </View>
        )
    }
```

MyPresentational layer:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View,Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
export default MachineFunctionality = (props) => {
    let acheivedPercentage = ((props.acheived_value/props.target_value)*100);
    let acheivedPercentageValue = acheivedPercentage;
    acheivedPercentage = acheivedPercentageValue + '%';
    return(
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.CardItem} 
        onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('MachineFunctionalityDetail')}>
            <Text style={{fontSize:18, color:'black'}}>{props.level}</Text>
            <Text style={{marginTop: 5}}>{props.taget_label}</Text>
            <View style={[styles.barContainer, {width:'100%'}]}>
                {/* <Text style={{textAlign:'center', fontSize:12, padding:2}}>100%</Text> */}
            </View>
            <Text style={{marginTop: 5}}>{props.acheived_label} ({Math.ceil(acheivedPercentageValue)}%)</Text>
            <View style={[styles.barContainer,{width: acheivedPercentage}]}>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    CardItem: {
        flex: 1,
        height:120,
        padding:8,
        backgroundColor:'#e7e7e7',
        borderRadius: 5,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        margin: 5,
        shadowColor: 'black',
        shadowOpacity: 0.8,
        elevation: 8
    },
    barText: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        fontSize: 13,
        margin: 10,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
    },
    barContainer: {
        height: 10,
        marginTop:5,
        backgroundColor:'lightskyblue',
        borderColor: 'blue',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderRadius: 3,
        shadowOpacity: 0,
        elevation: 2,
    },

})
```

MyNavigator

```
const MachineStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  MachineHome: {screen: AllMachine, navigationOptions:{header: null}},
  MachineFunctionalityDetail: {screen:MachineFunctionalityDetail, navigationOptions:{header: null}},
  MachineProfile:{screen:MachineProfile, navigationOptions:{header: null}}
})
```

Comment: Your component is a functional component. Use props.navigation.navigate instead of this.props.navigation.navigate.

Comment: I tried, but not working.

Comment: Did you already defined your Navigator? Can you add your navigator code to the question?

Comment: I have added my navigation snippet also.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a library for handling navigation problem and also prevent the usage of this.props.navigation prop.

### [React Navigation Helpers](https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-navigation-helpers)

Usage is very simple. On your App.js or your navigator simply set the global level navigator.

```
import NavigationService from "react-navigation-helpers";


<MainNavigator
  ref={navigatorRef =>
    NavigationService.setGlobalLevelNavigator(navigatorRef)
  }
/>
```

Then you use ANYWHERE on your project with this simple code segment:

```
NavigationService.navigate("home")
```

Of course, you still need to import the NavigationService :)

## UPDATED:

### How to pass prop with this library?

The usage does not change. Simply put your prop as the secondary prop **as same as React Navigation** itself.

Navigate

```js
NavigationService.navigate("home", {data: myData, myId: "d1f01df1" })
```

Push

```js
NavigationService.push("home", {data: myData, myId: "d1f01df1" })
```

### How to receive the passed props from navigation or push functions?

```js
const data = props.navigation.getParam("data", null) // Second one is default value
const myId = props.navigation.getParam("myId", "") // Second one is default value
```

You can find a more detailed document on the library's README. If you still have a question, feel free to ask, I will help you gladly.

The new release is here: [Release 0.1.0](https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-navigation-helpers/releases/tag/0.1.0)

Comment: How can I use this with react-navigation library.?

Comment: There is no specific config to use it. Simply set the global navigator and it will handle itself. You can check the Readme or it has even a working example in it :)

Comment: I have done the same and it's working only inside App.js. However, if I want to navigate from other component it says TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigator.dispatch')

Comment: Hey @vicky keshri, It works globally, not just App.js. I think you miss some parts. Can you please share with me how to implement it, I can help you.

Comment: It was my bad. I forgot to assign ref to app container. can you please help me with how can I pass props to other component with this library.

Comment: Sure, I'm updating the README now. Also, gonna update the Post itself. Coming in 5

Comment: @vickykeshri can you please check the updated post? Also you can check the README on the Github. I upgraded the new release 0.1.0 :) Please ask me anything if you have questions

Comment: Yea, got it. But again props are coming into picture. Can we do NavigationService.getParams('key'). The whole idea of using Navigation helper is to get rid of "this.props"

Comment: Yes, I will make it work this weekend. I haven't tried it but with 0.1.0, it expose navigator itself. Therefore, in theory you can you NavigationService.navigator.getParams, if it will not work I will make it work in this weekend :)

Comment: Have you worked on the things.? I am finding it difficult in implementation.

Comment: I could not work on it. But I will in this week. I will inform you when it is finished. Yes, it is hard to use to getParam thing. I will make it better :)

Answer (score 0):

First just use HOC provided by React Navigation such as **withNavigation** that injects the navigation prop.

Just Import **withNavigation** from react-navigation in your Presentational Component.

```
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation'; // Add this line
```

and  Export Your Presentational Component like this:

```
export default withNavigation(MachineFunctionality);
```

This way you don't have to change anything else in your component.

Comment: @vickykeshri did you try?? and one more  thing remove THIS keyword only use props.navigation.navigate('routename')